# How to place/insert a banner/image on the start/index page in shopware 6.4.x?

Tags: banner, shopware6

I need to place/insert a banner image on the startpage of a shopware 6.4.20.0 shop
but i can't find a description how to do this

On the shopware faq i found only a desription for shopware 5
One other description says go to **Marketing >> Banner** but the **Banner** link doesn't exists in shopware 6

I'm using a free version

Is it possible maybe with a free addon, a script or from the cms?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's indeed possible with the cms elements. The starting page is a "shopping experience".

In the categories section find the category that's the main navigation entry point for your sales channel. If you don't know which one that is go to the sales channel settings to find the correct category.

When editing the category switch to the layout tab and assign a layout. The layout content can be edited from the category detail page afterwards. If you want to change the structure of the layout head over to the shopping experiences which can be found in the content section of the admin menu.

More information on how to use the shopping experiences [can be found in the documentation](https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-6-en/content/ShoppingExperiences).

Comment: now i get it! i have to duplicate the main layout, edit it and then assign it because the main layout is locked. if you are only briefly involved with shopware then it is clear that you will not find it that way, but it will not appear in the search engines if you search afterwards, ty!